# How to get correct query in sql when field of coloumn has apex inside

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

i'm trying to do this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE value1='THIS'S AN EXAMPLE'.
```

The problem is that apex inside content will give error on query. how can i solve it? can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try escaping it like that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE value1='THIS''S AN EXAMPLE'
```

where `''` is 2 single quotes.

But best would be to make this a parametrized query. If you're running it from your code.

Comment: i'll use parametrized query ;) but double quotes is the right solution :)

Comment: sorry.. i try this: PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM ?");
       prep.setString(1, "table");
       ResultSet rs = prep.executeQuery(); but it give me exception: java.sql.SQLException: near "?": syntax error... why?

Comment: This is because you can't parametrize FROM argument. Use parameter in the WHERE clause: SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE value1=?

Answer (score 3):

In `oracle` you use `''` instead of one `'`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE value1='THIS''S AN EXAMPLE'.
```

In mysql you need to escape it with `\'`

read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html